# C# Read xml file that uses name prefixes but does not define namespace in the document itself

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an xml file from a client. It uses name prefixes with many nodes. But it does not defines any namespace in the document. A sample is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SemiconductorTestDataNotification>
  <ssdh:DocumentHeader>
    <ssdh:DocumentInformation>
      <ssdh:Creation>2019-03-16T13:49:23</ssdh:Creation>
    </ssdh:DocumentInformation>
  </ssdh:DocumentHeader>
  <LotReport>
    <BALocation>
      <dm:ProprietaryLabel>ABCDEF</dm:ProprietaryLabel>
    </BALocation>
  </LotReport>
</SemiconductorTestDataNotification>
```

I used following xml classes to read it but failed

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement
System.Xml.XmlDocument
System.Xml.XmlReader
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
```

It gives error:

> 'ssdh' is an undeclared prefix.

I know the prefixes namespaces. These would be:

```
xmlns:ssdh="urn:rosettanet:specification:system:StandardDocumentHeader:xsd:schema:01.13"
xmlns:dm="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Manufacturing:xsd:schema:01.14"
```

Adding these namespaces in the xml file by myself is not feasible because there would be many xml files and these files would come on daily basis.

Is it possible that I create a file (e.g. xsd) and write namespaces in them and read xml file using this (so called) schema file in C# code.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to fix missing namespace prefix in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43042099), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046080).  However, you'll need to slightly generalize the answer there to allow for multiple application-specified missing namespaces.  Does that answer your question, or do you need help adapting the answer there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a non xml method for reading bad xml file.  Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program1
    {
        const string BAD_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string Fixed_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(BAD_FILENAME);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Fixed_FILENAME);

            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line == "<SemiconductorTestDataNotification>")
                {
                    line = line.Replace(">", 
                        " xmlns:ssdh=\"urn:rosettanet:specification:system:StandardDocumentHeader:xsd:schema:01.13\"" +
                        " xmlns:dm=\"urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Manufacturing:xsd:schema:01.14\"" +
                        " >");
                }
                writer.WriteLine(line);

            }
            reader.Close();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Fixed_FILENAME);
        }
    }

}
```